# WebDriver InternetExplorerDriver: Could not get document window handle

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using Selenium InternetExplorerDriver to perform some basic actions. In this case, all I am trying to do is bring up IE and navigate to a webpage. So far, I am able to bring up IE, but all I see is: "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."

I've spent a lot of time trying to research this problem and have tried a few things, none of which worked. Two of the many things I've tried are:

1. Setting Protected mode on for all
2. Ignoring security settings completely

At this point, I am stuck and have no idea how to proceed with IE.

My code:

```
    public void setUp() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
    prop.load(inputStream);

    /** Set path for Log4j */
    String pathtolog4j = prop.getProperty("PathToLog4j");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(pathtolog4j);

    /** Bring up IEDriver & load application */
    String pathtoIEdriver = prop.getProperty("PathToIEDriver");
    File file = new File(pathtoIEdriver);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    logger.info("Get URL");
    String url = prop.getProperty("appURL");
    driver.navigate().to(url);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) 2.35.3.0 
Listening on port 4297
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Could not get document from window handle (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.80 seconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_43'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:151)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:201)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:184)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:147)
at TestScripts.Drivers.InternetExplorer.IEDriverSetup.setUp(IEDriverSetup.java:64)
```

Comment: You are running v2.33 of Selenium. Upgrade it to the latest first. Also try the 32-bit IE driver to see if there is any difference. What version of IE is it?

Comment: I upgraded Selenium to 2.35 and tried using the 32-bit driver, but no luck. I'm still getting the same error. I'm using IE10.

Comment: Downgraded to IE9 and that seemed to fix the problem. I still get the error occasionally and have to restart my IDEA instance and kill the IEDriver process for my script to be able to run again. Still need to figure out what is causing this to happen from time to time.